# Making aptitude less verbose

Tags: linux, debian, aptitude

People say that `aptitude` on Debian is so much better than `apt-get`, but I find it less usable. (See examples below.) Is there any configuration magic for `aptitude` to get rid of those useless status messages?

```
» aptitude install foo
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Reading extended state information...
Initializing package states...
Writing extended state information...
Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "foo"
Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "foo"
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B of archives. After unpacking 0B will be used.
Writing extended state information...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Reading extended state information...
Initializing package states...
```

Compare:

```
» apt-get install foo
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Couldn't find package foo
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can configure the quietness of aptitude (and apt-get) by putting a line such as:

```
quiet = "2";
```

at the beginning or end of `/etc/apt/apt.conf`.

Answer (score 10):

Try putting `-q`, `-q=2` or `-qq` at the end of your commands, for example:

```
sudo aptitude update -q=2
```

Comment: Is there any source documenting _what_ messages quiet mode does or does not filter?